# How do I initialize an array inside a method, when it is already declared as a global variable?

Tags: java

For a global variable:

```
int arr[][];
```

Inside the method:

```
arr[][]=new int[rows][columns];
```

This throws an error. How do I initialize an array inside a method if I already have one as a global variable?

Error thrown:-

arr[][]=new int [rows][columns]; -this statement is highlighted and the error message is 'not a statement'

Comment: Include the error message in your post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Java is a bit rusty, but have you tried:

```
arr = new int[rows][columns];
```

All small change in syntax, but this may get rid of your error.